# After Effects Questions

Tags: discussion

Can I ask questions such as *how to create this in After Effects* here?

Also, does questions related to **motion graphics** and **visual effects** allowed here? Is there a separate **StackExchange** for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, After Effects and effects work in general is extremely on topic here and there are quite a few questions already.  Please be sure to be as descriptive of the effect you are trying to accomplish though so we are certain to understand what you are trying to accomplish.